# How will a particle with energy less than $V_{\rm min}$ behave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

Consider e.g. the finite square well: $V = -V_o$ between $x=-a$ and $x=a$, $V=0$ elsewhere

Now for scattering states, $E$ must be $> 0$. For normalizable bound states, $E$ must be $< 0$ and $> V_{\rm min}$ (=$-V_o$ in example).

But if a particle in a lab has Energy which $< 0$ and $<V_{\rm min}$, is it bound or will it scatter?

And I don't know why I haven't thought about this before but what does it mean for a photon to have negative energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particle with have an unphysical wave function which blows up (as can be quite easily derived). Therefore, in quantum mechanics, we do *not* have any particles with $E<V_\text{min}$.

Comment: Disregarding the mathematical blowing up of the wavefunction, practically we create a particle with the energy we want and then we pass it through a particular potential function(the particle doesn't "see" the potential Vmin until it comes across it). So I can't see why we can't create a particle with an energy value less than Vmin and then pass it through the potential. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: 'Disregarding the mathematical blowing up' is simply discarding the physical reasonableness of your theory. A nonrenormalizable wave function makes no sense in terms of probabilities.

Comment: ok my comment didn't come off like I intended. What I meant is that sometimes real physics happens where current mathematical models can't go. And in particular, Normalizability shouldn't be an indicator as to whether a particle with a certain energy can exist or not; particles with scattering state energies don't have normalizable wavefunctions, for instance.

Comment: I assume you're talking about momentum eigenstates of, for instance, a free particle? In that case, that's exactly why those don't actually exist: We must have a superposition of momentum eigenstates (i.e. a wave packet) for things to work out.

Answer (score 4):

If $E< V(x) $ everywhere, and if we assume that the kinetic energy operator $T=\frac{p^{\dagger}p}{2m}$ is a [(semi)positive operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_element), then the [TISE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) implies

$$ 0 ~\leq~ \langle \psi | T | \psi \rangle ~=~ \langle \psi | (E-V) | \psi \rangle~<~ 0, $$

which is impossible.  Here $H=T+V$ is the Hamiltonian operator.