# Stationary State of Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

Why for every normalized solution to the time-independent Schrödinger equation $E$ must exceed the minimum value of $V(x)$?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How will a particle with energy less than $V_{\rm min}$ behave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107235/)

Comment: This is a neat (and not quite obvious) conceptual question at the level of a first QM class. It might be a little easier to understand if you frame it in terms of *"Why is the (magnitude of the) time-independent wave-function of a particle whose energy is less than the minimum potential monotonic?"*